# Transformar estas regras Web.config em .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, web.config

Boa noite,

Estou precisando passar essas parte de um web.config para .htaccess, mas estou com bastante dúvida.

```
<rule name="Regla 1-1">
              <match url="^camera/pictures/(.*)_small\.png$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="camera/pictures/{R:1}.png" />
            </rule> 
            <rule name="Regla 2-2">
              <match url="^camera/thumbnails/(.*)\.png$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="camera/thumbnails/{R:1}.png" />
            </rule>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que faz a segunda regra? Reescreve para o mesmo URL???

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, é sim. O mais importante é a primeira... Quando reescrevo, não dá certo.

Answer (score 0):

Quase não há necessidade de explicar.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^camera/pictures/(.*)_small\.png$ /camera/pictures/$1.png
```

- Veja [**`RewriteRule`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) para mais informações.

A segunda regra reescreve para o mesmo URL. Não é necessária.

Comment: Só a barra `/` antes do camera que esta "parcialmente errada" `/camera/pictures/$1.png`, só mudar para isto `camera/pictures/$1.png`, de esto a resposta me parece correta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu [tinha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/217576/revisions) isso assim mas modifiquei para [tratá-lo como um `file-system path`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rhs) como primeira opção, da mesma maneira que as `<rules>` [funcionam em relação à localização do Web.config](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rewrite-rules-scope).

Comment: É que tem a questão do `RewriteBase`, depois vou testar e confirmo, só pra ter certeza, mas recordo-me que isto pode causar algum problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode causar algum problema com `VirtualHost`s, com um `DocumentRoot` diferente. É verdade que é recomendado sem o `/`, mas a resposta imita o comportamento das `<rule>`s.

Comment: Entendo, vou testar aqui assim que possivel, tenho IIS e Apache2.4 instalados e te aviso ;)

Comment: Obrigado. Também estou interessado em saber se há exceções.